# Iterating over timestamp row values within a column and performing a countif in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Right now I have a view called `dates` that looks like this:

```
|first_day|last_day|
|---------|--------|
|2020-08-17T00:00:00+00:00|2020-12-04T00:00:00+00:00|
|2020-11-23T00:00:00+00:00|2020-12-07T00:00:00+00:00|
|2020-09-14T00:00:00+00:00|2020-12-04T00:00:00+00:00|
|2020-09-14T00:00:00+00:00|2020-12-04T00:00:00+00:00|
|2020-09-14T00:00:00+00:00|2020-12-04T00:00:00+00:00|
```

...
of about 300 rows...

I created another view to generate a row of dates starting from June 01/2020 to today (Whatever that day is) with this SQL query:

```
SELECT GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2020-06-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS date
```

Which generates a table like this (we will call this `dateseries`):

```
|date|
|----|
|2020-06-01 00:00:00 UTC|
|2020-06-02 00:00:00 UTC|
|2020-06-03 00:00:00 UTC|
|2020-06-04 00:00:00 UTC|
```

... Starting from June 1/2020 till current_timestamp in 1 DAY INTERVALS till whatever the current date is.

Now what I want to do is iterate over each row value in `dateseries` and check within the `dates` view if that time stamp value (from `dateseries`) is greater then `first_day` column AND  less then`last_day` column. If it is, count 1. So its pretty much two loops. The first loop is iterating over every value in `dateseries` then comparing it to every row in `dates` view, comparing the two columns first_day and last_day. I guess another way of thinking about it is if the value from `dateseries` is between first_day and last_day columns within the dates view, then count 1 else 0.

In the end I want a table that looks like this (date column is same timeseries from June1 -> current_timestamp()):

```
|date|count|
|----|-----|
|2020-06-01 00:00:00 UTC|32|
|2020-06-02 00:00:00 UTC|31|
|2020-06-03 00:00:00 UTC|22|
|2020-06-04 00:00:00 UTC|5|
|2020-06-05 00:00:00 UTC|16|
```

...etc...

How would I do this in BigQuery SQL?

EDIT: Not sure why the table syntax isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with dateseries as (
  select date
  from unnest(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2020-06-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS date
)
select date, count(1) `count` 
from `project.dataset.dates`
join dateseries
on date between first_day and last_day
group by date
```

Note: first_day and last_day columns in `project.dataset.dates` assumed to be of timestamp data type. Otherwise (if they are strings) - use below  line

```
on date between timestamp(first_day) and timestamp(last_day)
```

Comment: This returns a query with one row with date and count as columns. Everytime I rerun the query it returns a random date and count. Not sure whats wrong here. Also when I run SELECT * FROM dateseries it just returns 1 row...

Comment: you should check your view and what it produces. based on your comment - it might produce random data by itself. rather than this - above answer should (and does) work as it is asked in your question!!!

Comment: Ive refreshed my page and reran the query and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to `JOIN` both tables on `date` being between `first_day` and `last_day` and count rows:

```sql
SELECT ds.date, COUNT(d.first_day) AS count
FROM dateseries ds
JOIN dates d ON ds.date BETWEEN d.first_day AND d.last_day
GROUP BY ds.date
ORDER BY ds.date
```

Note it's not 100% clear what end conditions you want for the dates; you may want to use

```sql
JOIN dates d ON ds.date > d.first_day AND ds.date < d.last_day
```

Comment: @JeStra sorry - wasn't thinking. I've edited the answer.